# Set variable with new line and tab

Tags: python-2.7, string-formatting

Formatting issue that is getting passed to document. Sample companyList below which varies each time script is run

```
companyList = ["Apple - Seattle Washington (800) 555-5555", "Microsoft - Tampa Florida (800) 555-1234", "Samsung - Tokyo Japan (01) 555 123-1234"]
```

Right now the line of code to format this text is:

```
companyInfo = "\n\n".join(companyList)
```

and companyInfo outputs like this:

```
Apple - Seattle Washington (800) 555-5555 Microsoft - Tampa Florida (800) 555-1234  Samsung - Tokyo Japan (01) 555 123-1234
```

How can I rewrite this to format like this (note tabbed one over per new line):

```
    Apple - Seattle Washington (800) 555-5555
    Microsoft - Tampa Florida (800) 555-1234
    Samsung - Tokyo Japan (01) 555 123-1234
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
companyInfo = "\n\n".join("\t%s" % x for x in companyList)
```

Comment: This works great and I will find very useful in general, however, I am actually writing this variable to a matching variable in a word document xml template and the formatting doesn't appear to be holding in this scenario. Sorry I didn't mention it earlier, didn't think it would matter. You did answer question as asked, so thanks.